# Find column based on header and remove first 3 characters starting from 2 row

Tags: excel, vba

I need help to remove character from a column with particular header.

I have a spreadsheet with headers (IP, hostname, Asset Group). I need to remove the first 3 characters from each row of the column called "Asset Group" (excluding header name (row 1)). Basically, I want to get rid of the "VM " from that column. I have a problem how to refer to that particular column "Asset Group". Thank you in advance!

[image]

```
    Dim SelRange As Range
    Dim ColNum As Integer
    Dim CWS As Worksheet
    
        'Find the column number where the column header is Asset Group
    
        Set CWS = ActiveSheet
        ColNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Asset Group", CWS.Rows(1), 0)
        
        LastColumn = Cells(1, CWS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = 2 To LastColumn
        
            ...
        
        Next i
    
    End With
    
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following

```
Dim CWS As Worksheet
Dim AssetHdr as Range
Dim tmp as Variant
Dim i as Long

Set CWS = ActiveSheet

' Find Header Column
Set AssetHdr = CWS.Rows(1).Find(what:="Asset Group")

' Test if Header was found
If Not AssetHdr is Nothing Then
    With CWS
        ' Get Last Row in Column
        NoRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, AssetHdr.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Store in array
        tmp = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(2, AssetHdr.Column), .Cells(NoRow, AssetHdr.Column))).Value2
        ' Remove first 3 characters
        For i = LBound(tmp) to UBound(tmp)
            tmp(i) = Right(tmp(i), Len(tmp(i))-3)
        Next i
        ' Write back to sheet
        .Cells(2, AssetHdr.Column).Resize(ubound(tmp)-1).Value2 = tmp
    End With
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

### Replace Partial Strings in a Range

- `Application.Match` allows you to test its result with `IsError` or `IsNumeric`, while `WorksheetFunction.Match` raises an error if no match.
- With the [`Range.Replace method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) you can replace values in a range in one go.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ReplacePartialString()
    
    Dim cws As Worksheet: Set cws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim ColNum As Variant
    ColNum = Application.Match("Asset Group", cws.Rows(1), 0)
    
    If IsError(ColNum) Then
        MsgBox "Column 'Asset Group' not found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Set LastCell = cws.Cells(cws.Rows.Count, ColNum).End(xlUp)
    
    If LastCell.Row < 2 Then
        MsgBox "No data found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = cws.Range(cws.Cells(2, ColNum), LastCell)
    
    crg.Replace "VM ", "", xlPart, , True
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out how to do it, the way I started. Thanks for the answer @VBasic2008, you created a better one with catching errors.

```
Dim CWS As Worksheet

Set CWS = ActiveSheet
ColNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Asset Group", CWS.Rows(1), 0)

With CWS
       LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColNum).End(xlUp).Row
End With
For i = 2 To LR
       CWS.Cells(i, ColNum) = Right(CWS.Cells(i, ColNum).Value, Len(CWS.Cells(i, ColNum).Value) - 3)
Next i
```